# Filter to show sub tasks of a filtered list of parent tasks

Tags: filter, task, jira

I have a JIRA filter which returns all the fixes in a future release:

`project = MyProject AND fixVersion = "1.1.1" and issuetype in standardIssueTypes() and status != Closed`

All of these issues have Sub-Tasks which I want to have in a new filter result. They do not have the `fixVersion` set.

I have tried the `parent` filter but this only accepts Key or ID.

Is there any way I can write a filter to access these without manually using something like `parent in (MyProject-1,MyProject-2,MyProject-3,MyProject-4,etc)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a solution that requires no plugins whatsoever, but some manual work that is much better than listing the tasks in the query itself:

Using the linkedIssues function, you can write a query like so

```
parent in linkedIssues("PROJ-1061")
```

Now, link all the issues you want in this query to the PROJ-1061 and you're golden. You can do this in a bulk job, you can also add it as a trigger in a workflow potentially.

Comment: this wasn't available in the version of jira we were using at the time

Comment: It would be perfect, but I am not able bulk-add the link to many issues. I have ~50 issues to link and doing it manually is a nightmare. Any suggestion? (using jira cloud)

Comment: This did not work for me without the plugin. I get the error message "JQLT Custom field is not configured. Please check with your administrator".

Comment: For JIRA v7.6.9 : [issue in descendantIssues("PROJ-XX")](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Filter-Get-issues-by-epic-with-their-subtasks/qaq-p/452202#M314579)

Answer (score 16):

You can install the Craftforge JQL functions
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/31601

You then create a filter

> project = MyProject AND fixVersion = "1.1.1" and issuetype in standardIssueTypes() and status != Closed

Call this filter for example 'parentIssues'

Using the JQL

> issue in subtaskIssuesFromFilter("parentIssues")

will retrieve all relevant subtask issues.

Comment: Looks exactly what I need! Unfortunately I am not an admin of the server. I have passed it on to see if the admin will install it.

Comment: You can tell your admin that we are using it in production, and that we didn't encounter an issue until now.

Comment: He is ok with the plugin, but our version of JIRA is too old. He is using it as an excuse to do the upgrade that has been put off for a while!

Answer (score 7):

Use [Script Runner](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions) plugin and a query like:

```
issueFunction in subtasksOf("project = MyProject AND fixVersion = 27_04_2013 and status != Closed"))
```

Answer (score 4):

JQL Tricks adds tons of additional JQL functions: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin

Here an example for the above using their syntax:

`issue in parent("project = MyProject AND fixVersion = 27_04_2013 and status != Closed")`

Answer (score -13):

There is no need for any Plugin.

Switch to "Advanced" filter option and enter

```
status in ("Open") AND parent in (PHX-xxx,ENG-xxx)
```

It will give you all the open tickets present as a subtask in parent JIRAs. Build more complex and enjoy using JIRA. Advanced filter options will also give you all possible values to build Queries.

Comment: How does "PHX-xxx" work?   Is this some sort of wildcard?   I can't see how this is a filtered list of parent tasks (as per the question).

Comment: The xxx is a placeholder, they're just examples, you'd put the actual project/issue code in there.

Comment: What he wants is to get all open sub-tasks on closed parents. Your solution force him to add each and every parent-id.

Comment: parent = <parent-id> AND status = open worked for me

Comment: asker specifically did not want this solution.