# Is it possible to search JIRA for a list of subtasks whose parents are found in a different query?

Tags: jira, jql

I have a filter to return a group of parent tasks based on some criteria.

I can use this as a group of issues to search further using `filter = FilterName`
What I would like to be able to do is to use this in the parent field search in something like

`parent IN (filter = FilterName)`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The IN operator expects a comma-delimited list.  While I'm not sure of a way to retrieve the information you're looking for solely using the built-in JQL, the question has been asked before and an answer was accepted based on using a plug-in.

[Filter to show sub tasks of a filtered list of parent tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153024/filter-to-show-sub-tasks-of-a-filtered-list-of-parent-tasks)

The good news is the [Craftforge JQL](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/31601) plug-in referenced is <strike>free</strike>.

UPDATE: As Micky mentioned in the comments, this plugin is no longer free as of version 2.0 (16 Apr 2013)

Comment: Is this possible without a plugin?

Comment: **Bryan** - the _Craftforge JQL_ plug-in is **no longer free**.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Micky.  I updated the comment.  I also noticed there's an open issue over at Atlassian for this.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-18918

Answer (score 1):

The [Scripted JQL Functions](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions) included with the free [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin will let you do what you need.

For example:

```
issueFunction in subTasksOf("filter = FilterName")
```

Comment: thanks to share it with us. This function solved my problem.