# How to get the parent issuetype of a sub-task?

Tags: filter, jira, jql

Hiding Stories and User Stories in one board isn't a problem since the filters do a great job. The problem is that their sub-tasks still show up in this board.

JQL is missing the function to look up what issuetype the parent has. We tried the app "Scriprunner" and it works great, fantastic. For one single line of code the price is absolutely insane tough.

Is there another way to hide certain Sub-Tasks or does a free Add-On exist that adds the requied functionality to JQL?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it could be done without extra plugins.
Please take a look at [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Searching-for-subtasks-of-parents-that-meet-certain-criteria/qaq-p/39736) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153024/filter-to-show-sub-tasks-of-a-filtered-list-of-parent-tasks).

These plugins could help you to do what you want (though all of them are payd):

- [Script Runner](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions)
- [JQL Tricks Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin/server/overview)
- [Search Linked Issues (Craftforge JQL Functions Plugin)](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.craftforge.jira.craftforge-jql-functions-plugin/server/overview)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use tagging as a method for showing different issues on a board or for removing them. While it's less efficient than using a plugin and less ideal than having Jira do this natively - in the short term it could solve your issue.

Adding tags to your issues and then either using JQL to filter them out:

`AND labels NOT IN ('my-exluded-tag','this-other-excluded-tag')`

or

`AND labels IN ('my-included-tag','my-other-included-tag')`

Like I said, not perfect but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The subtasks are usually different Issue type and you may create quick filter with all of them e.g.:
"type not in ("Development task", "Story Bug")" assuming both in the example are subtask issue types.

Also another useful thing if you have "JWME - Misc Workflow Plugin" is to add "Post Action" in your workflow that transition the subtasks once the parent is transitioned / closed.

[image]

[image]

[image]